# Is there anyway to make a div horizontally scrollable without needing to hold down shift?

Tags: html, css

In order to scroll horizontally through a content box, you need to hold down shift. I fear many people visiting the site won't know to. Is there a way to make it scroll when you just use the scroll wheel without needing to hold down shift as well?

Comment: You can use jQuery to prevent default scroll behavior. [This CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) has a method you can implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the mouse position and scroll the pag when the mouse is close to the browser window's edge. But you should use javascript. Not html or css for what you want.